# Login Failed In Domain Server Through ASPX

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, exception

I have `domain` server and `mssql` database with it. When I run the `aspx` page through the `domain` server it gives me exception. I have `password` and `username` for the `sql` database in the `domain` server maybe this is the problem. What should I do to fix it ?

Exception:

```
Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
```

Connection String:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="sky_PeopleEntities"
        connectionString="metadata=res://*/hosting.csdl|res://*/hosting.ssdl|res://*/hosting.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=go.db.hosting.bg;initial catalog=sky_People;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
        providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: What does your connection string look like?

Comment: I added the connection string.

Comment: Take some time and properly format your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The login failed with that error means that the server/computer you're making the SQL connection from is apart of a different Active Directory domain than the one that the SQL server is on.

Normally this means that you need add a user name or password to the connection string so you can authenticate using SQL Authentication instead of Windows Authentication. You'll probably need to talk to the hosting company, or system admin to get the username and password setup correctly.

Once you have that, remove the `integrated security=true` part, and add `User Id=[username];
Password=[password];`

Comment: Should I add user and password exactly in [ ] brackets ?

Comment: Without the `[]`. I was just using those to tell you to change those values for your environment. Should end up like `User Id=testuser; Password=testpass;`

Answer (score 1):

integrated security=True is the problem: double hopp issue.

Fix it by providing proper SQL username and password or with a correct application pool identity who has right to access the SQL server and the necessary resources.

Comment: How can I provide SQL username and password and what integrated security to write ?